# Apache 2.4, PHP 7.4 will not load mysqli extension

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

I have been searching for an answer for days now and nothing I've found has worked for me.
I am using Windows 10 Pro, Apache/2.4.52 (Win64), PHP 7.4.27, phpMyAdmin 5.1.2, MySQL 8.0.28.0

in a nutshell:
php says:
file C:\Apache24\php74\ext\php_mysqli.dll exists, Windows agrees
the statement $Database = new mysqli($localdb_host, $localdb_user, $localdb_pwd, $localdb_name); throws
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found

php.ini file contains:
extension_dir = 'C:\Apache24\php74\ext'
; extension=mysqli  ; this didn't include mysqli according to phpMyAdmin or phpinfo()
extension='C:\Apache24\php74\ext\php_mysqli.dll'    ; nor did this

phpinfo() shows
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) PHP/7.4.27
PATH    C:\Windows\System32, C:\Apache24\php74, C:\Apache24\php74, C:\Apache24\php74; C:\Apache24\php74\ext;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
No mention of mysqli
does show mysqlnd (Version  mysqlnd 7.4.27 )

Windows says its environment settings for PATH are
user: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps; C:\Apache24\php74
system: %PATH%; C:\Apache24\php74\ext

Windows Services show MySQL80 is running

phpMyAdmin says:
phpMyAdmin - Error
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.

Any help will be most gratefully received and appreciated.

Comment: you need to install php-mysqli extension, I don't know how to do that on windows, but on linux you can do sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysqli.

Comment: The `;` at the start of the line `extension=mysqli` means that line is commented out and ignored when loading the config. To enable the module, remove the `;` from that line and restart Apache.

Comment: thank you for your input Rao and Rick - the system keeps telling me
php[9916]
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: C:\PHP81\ext\mysqli (The specified module could not be found.), C:\PHP81\ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) 
But I have no clue as to why it is looking for PHP81 - I suspect it is a hangover from using xampp which I uninstalled.